# How to assert operators < and >= are not implemented?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, exception, python-unittest

Initially I was not using the `unittest` framework, so to test that two objects of the same class are not comparable using the operators `<` and `>=` I did something like:

```
try:
    o1 < o2
    assert False
except TypeError:
    pass
```

after that, though, I decided to start using the `unittest` module, so I'm converting my tests to the way tests are written with the same module.

I was trying to accomplish the equivalent thing as above with:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, o1 < o2)
```

but this does not quite work, because `o1 < o2` tries to call the operator `<`, instead of being a reference to a function, which should be called as part of the test.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need without needing to wrap `o1 < o2` in a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    o1 < o2
```

[Here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) is an explanation of the `with` statement. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) are the docs. TL;DR: It allows the execution of a code block with a "context", i.e. things to be set up and disposed before/after the execution, error handling etc.

In the case of `assertRaises`, its context manager simply checks whether an execption of the required type has been raised, by checking the `exc` agrument passed to its `__exit__` method.

Comment: How does this work actually? What's the logic behind this exactly?

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti For a user who gained quite some rep you seem to skip the acceptance of an answer to your questions quite often. Is there any reason why you didn't accept this specific answer? I even provided the background information you requested.

Comment: I'm not sure yet if the code would work as I expect, because, if I understood correctly, this `with` statement would just call the `__exit__` of the object returned by the `self.assertRaises(TypeError)` function, but,  if not exception is raised, I think the code would still work. But I want the code to fail if it does not throw a `TypeError` exception.

Comment: What you describe is exactly the behaviour of `assertRaises`. The unit test fails, if no `TypeError` is thrown, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).