# assertRaises in unittest not catching Exception properly

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda, python-3.5, python-unittest

I have a file testtest.py that i contains the code

```
import unittest

def add(self, a, b):
    return a + b

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_additon(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, add, 1 + '1', msg="Additon failed")
        #self.assertRaises(TypeError, lambda: add(1 + '1'), msg="Addition failed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is that `assertRaises` doesn't catch the exception properly and all my tests keep failing as errors not based on the condition, this is the output that I'm getting:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_additon (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testtest.py", line 9, in test_additon
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, add, 1 + '1', msg="Additon failed")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I know i can get around it by using lambda (i commented it out in the code) to make my tests properly catch the exceptions, but according to the docs, passing a callable and the arguments to `assertRaises` should work, as it will call the function internally by itself and be able to trap any exception that was raised.

```
assertRaises(*callable*, *args*, *kwargs*)
```

but it doesn't

if i run it with lambda which is a callable that would be evaluated later by `assertRaises`, it works as expected and i get this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

`I'm running python 3.5`

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 28 2016, 08:46:01) 
[GCC 6.1.1 20160602] on linux
```

but i also get the same behaviour with `python2.7`

Comment: You could also try using [assertRaises as a context manager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39224917/4806820)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing arguments to the callable *separately*, as separate arguments:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, add, 1, '1', msg="Additon failed")
```

Comment: facepalm moment...thanks @alexce i knew it had to be something simple but i couldn't pinpoint it...because i had done this several times and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
def test_additon(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        add(1 + '1')
```

The problem is that the exception is raised during argument evaluation before self.assertRaises can kick in.

Comment: your answer will also work also, but i was just wondering why it didn't work the way i wanted to do it....look at @alexce's answer

Comment: Yep, that's even better - we posted at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I made a silly mistake, I called the function being tested twice, and the `assertRaises()` was in the second call to the function.
Hence the `Exception` was being raised in the first call, even before the second call was executed!

Hope this helps anyone hitting this page when debugging.

Comment: Fell for a very similar mistake myself