# Why does python unittest assertRaises method not register exceptions that are thrown?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, assert, valueerror

I have a problem similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448269/assertraises-in-unittest-not-catching-exception-properly), however the solution doesn't help me as I only pass one argument to the function.

I have the following code:

```
def outer():
    def tuple_unpacker( mytuple ):
        try:
            a,b,c = mytuple
            return a+b+c
        except ValueError:
            print('pass tuple with exactly 3 elements')
        except TypeError:
            print('pass only integers in tuple')

    return tuple_unpacker
```

which I test using the python unittest module. However, even when my exceptions are raised, the assertions fail.

```
class TestInner(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_tuple_unpacker(self):
        func = outer()
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, func, (1,'a',1))
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, func, (1,1,1,1))
```

When I run this, the traceback is:

```
pass only integers in tuple
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_tuple_unpacker (__main__.TestInner)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malte/TDDE23_git/lab5/test_test.py", line 21, in test_tuple_unpacker
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, func, (1,'a',1))
AssertionError: TypeError not raised by tuple_unpacker

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

As you can see, it printed `pass only integers in tuple` so the exception was thrown.

The problem is the same if i switch places so the ValueError is tested first and fails.

Weirdly enough, if i change the assertions to:

```
class TestInner(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_tuple_unpacker(self):
        func = outer()
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, func((1,'a',1)))
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, func((1,1,1,1)))
```

It works for the TypeError, but not the ValueError.

Here is the traceback:

```
pass only integers in tuple
pass tuple with exactly 3 elements
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_tuple_unpacker (__main__.TestInner)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malte/TDDE23_git/lab5/test_test.py", line 22, in test_tuple_unpacker
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, func((1,1,1,1)))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 731, in assertRaises
    return context.handle('assertRaises', args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 201, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Thankful for all guidance.

Comment: Congratulations, you discovered a bug! Your function catches and supresses the exception. Your test expects the exception to be reraised. So, either that function or your test has a bug.

Comment: As an aside, the reason it works for `TypeError` in the second method is because you are passing the return value `None` to `assertRaises` which attempts to call it (`None()`) and raises a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tuple_unpacker` prints and then suppresses `TypeError` and `ValueError` exceptions. Your test checks for these exceptions but since the exceptions aren't reraised, the test fails. Either the function or the test has a bug and needs to change.